# Possible to create token and metadata in one transaction?

Tags: metaplex

Am I correct in saying that it's not possible to mint(create) an spl token and token metadata in the one transaction ?

Here is me cerating the mpl token metadata for a previously cerated spl token:

```
const createMetadataTx = new CreateMetadataV2(
      { feePayer: this.appTreasPair.publicKey },
      {
        metadata,
        metadataData: new DataV2({
          uri: `${host}/token_type/${token_type.token_type_id}/metadata`,
          name: token_type.name,
          symbol: token_type.symbol,
          sellerFeeBasisPoints: 100,
          creators: null,
          collection: null,
          uses: null,
          tokenStandard: TokenStandard.FungibleAsset,
        }),
        updateAuthority: this.appTreasPair.publicKey,
        mint: new web3.PublicKey(token_type.token_address),
        mintAuthority: this.appTreasPair.publicKey,
      }
    );

    const connection = solanaUtils.getConnection(token_type.cluster);

    const transaction = new web3.Transaction();

    console.log("creating metadata")
    transaction.add(createMetadataTx)

    const sig = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [this.appTreasPair], {
      skipPreflight: skipPreflight
    })
```

the `mint` field needs the address of the spl token which I can only get if I do the spl token creation in an initial separate transaction

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. E.g. candy machine is creating a SPL token and then assign metadata to it.
If you want a NFT: https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#mint-the-nft

If you rather want a standard SPL token the current method is create the SPL Token and then add it to the Solana Token list https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list (a better solution is WIP)

Comment: are you fully sure about this? it seems that to create the metadata you first need the address of the spl token that you want to apply the metadata to which implies 2 separate transactions.. I'll add some code to the original question above to demostrate..

Comment: Yes. You can create a SPL token at a given address so you would know it.

Comment: hmm didn't know this.. don't suppose you have an example ?